# C write file as executable ASCII

Tags: c, linux, executable

I'm making some program with a server sending a shell script to a client. the client gets the code and puts it in a file, and later exec it.

The adding function :

```
void addScript(char *name,char *content){
    int fd;
    char path[BUFSIZ];
    strcpy(path,"scripts/");
    strcat(path,name);
    strcat(path,".sh");
    printf("file : %s\n",path);
    fd = open(path,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,S_IRWXU|S_IRGRP);
    if(fd == -1){
        printf("Error openning file !!");
        return;
    }
    write(fd,content,strlen(content));
    write(fd,"\n",1);
    close(fd);
}
```

I have the file, but when I try to run it exec gives me an error :

```
Exec failed : Exec format error
```

I ran file command on the script, it gives me :

```
mount.sh: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text
```

Whereas on a hand-written script (working this one) I have :

```
diskUse.sh: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

I can't find how to force file type when I create it with my function, would anyone have an idea ? Thanks !

**Edit** some more details :

---

Example of a non-working file :

```
#!/bin/sh

mount
```

"Funny" thing is that it works well if I run it by hand from my shell (zsh) with ./mount.sh, but I have the warning :

```
./mount.sh: line 1: #!/bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

But :

```
$ ll /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 30 déc.  23:08 /bin/sh -> bash
```

---

Var content is a char *, sent throught network. The user types it in a web interface, it's then stored in a SQLite3 database, before being sent through network.

Comment: What is the content of `char *content`? Most likely this string has non-ASCII characters.

Comment: You can not define a `file` type. The type is guessed from the contents.

Comment: I guess your script is missing the shebang, but I'm not sure (you are not giving much details). Make sure your script is prefixed with `#/bin/bash` (assuming yours is a Bash script).

Comment: @axiac If no permissions the error would be different.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Still sounds like the next few bytes after that are wrong.  Also, are you sure this text lands in the file properly?

Comment: You should check the result of `write` and you might use `strace` to understand what is happenning

Comment: View your non-working file in a hex editor, look for strange characters. Also, make sure you have the correct newlines in that file, such as just `\n`. If you're using windows newlines `\r\n` your shell script will not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had non-printable chars which appeared with hexedit, works now.

thank you all !

Comment: Since these Q&As are intended to help others who ask the same question, maybe you could elaborate on how the garbage characters snuck in?

Comment: @Potatoswatter I forgot to clean a buffer, so filling with strncat left some data from allocation.